# VLAN - Tagging Query

Tags: dhcp, vlan

I have a netgear switch and the following configuration is working.

```
   VLAN ID  PORTS
        1   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
        10  1 2 3       7 8 
        20      3 4 5     8
```

Each port is untagged in the Vlan. eg: VLAN **20** ports `3,4,5 & 8` are untagged.

The result of the above is anything connected to port `1, 2 & 7` can't see anything in port `3, 4 & 5`.

Port `8` is a link to my router and port `3` a PC that sits across all VLANS.

This works as I want.

I have a device I'd like to add to connect to port 3, but using VLAN tagging on the device have it sit in VLAN 10 and get a DHCP address from VLAN 10.

On the device I've set VLAN 10 and on power up it just sits there waiting for DHCP..

Should this work ?

Thanks

**UPDATE**
When the device is plugged into a LAN port on my router, I see no activity on the DHCP Server.

When it's connected to a port in VLAN10 I get activity on the DHCP server, but the device doesn't get a DHCP address.

Comment: What is providing DHCP for VLAN 10? If it's the router, it has to recognize tagged VLAN 10 traffic and have a DHCP scope defined for that subnet.

Comment: ...does the router have all VLANs _untagged_ on the same port? How can that even possibly work?